# Javascript Calculator will not clear after answer is given

Tags: javascript, calculator, nan

When I open this up in my browser I am able to enter the equation I want but after I the answer to display I can not get the calculator to reset. After I get NaN I am stuck. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function divide()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "/";
        }
        function add()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "+";
        }
        function num9()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "9";
        }
        function num8()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "8";
        }
        function num7()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "7";

        }
        function multiply()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "*";
        }
        function percent()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "%";
        }
        function num6()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "6";
        }
        function num5()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "5";
        }

        function num4()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "4";
        }


        function subtr()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "-";
        }

        function num3()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "3";
        }

        function num2()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "2";
        }

        function num1()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "1";
        }

        function numZero()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "0";
        }

        function buildFormula()
        {
            var evalu= alert(eval(document.calculator.output.value)) + document.clear();
            document.calculator.output.value= evalu;
        }


    </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="calculator">

<table border=0>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4><input type=text readonly=true name="output" size = 25></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   7   "  onClick="num7()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   8   " onClick="num8()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   9   " onClick="num9()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    /  " onClick="divide()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "     + " onClick="add()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   4   " onClick="num4()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   5 " onClick="num5()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   6  " onClick= "num6()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    *   " onClick= "multiply()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    %    " onClick="percent()"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=button value = "   1   " onClick="num1()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   2   " onClick="num2()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   3   " onClick="num3()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "    -    " onClick="subtr()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "     =     " onClick="buildFormula()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=5><input type=button value = "             0             " onClick="numZero()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: What are you doing to "reset"?

Comment: If ever you have very repetitive code like that, something deep down inside should tell you that something's wrong.

Comment: I guess that might be my problem. I do not have a clear button on my calculator. I guess I thought I could just delete the NaN and start over.

Comment: Okay so instead of "7" just use 7? Should I keep my +,-,*,/ in ""?

Comment: @JayHarris: Have you considered that your sentence makes no sense to someone who's never heard of the website you're referring to? That said, if you want a demo, you should make one. All the info is right there.

Comment: shorter: http://jsfiddle.net/5qLaQ/

Answer (score 2):

your problem because you're trying to summarize return from `alert` with return from `document.clear()` - this is wrong, alert returns nothing and document.clear is undefined method

change you function to this one:

```
 function buildFormula()
    {
        var evalu= eval(document.calculator.output.value);
        document.calculator.output.value= '';
        alert(evalu);
    }
```

Comment: This worked. I also took my numbers out of the "". Thank you so much.

Comment: +1 bc i was going in the wrong direction, lol didn't realize it till i put it in a fiddle